# Overriding the way JMX works in a Docker WLS container

Tags: weblogic, docker, jmx

I have a WebLogic docker container. The WLS admin port is configured at 7001. When I run the container, I use --hostname=[hosts' hostname] and expose the 7001 port at a different host port using -p 8001:7001 for example. The reason I do the port mapping is because I would want to run multiple WLS containers on the same host.

I have some applications that I deploy on this WebLogic. These applications use an external SDK (which I don't control) to get the application url using JMX (getURL operation of RuntimeServiceMBean).

This is where it gets wrong. The URL comes out as http://[container's IP]:7001. I would want it to retrieve http://[hosts' hostname]:8001 - i.e. the hostname I used to start the container and the port at which 7001 is mapped i.e. 8001.

Is there a way this could be done?

Answer (score 0):

When the container is started, you should start WebLogic after adjusting the External Listen Address of your AdminServer. You can use WLST Offline for that from within a shell script, passing parameters with docker run -e KEY=VALUE, then later read these from inside the WLST script. Modify your AdminServer External Listen Address, exit(), then you can start AdminServer.

[Here's an example](http://www.ateam-oracle.com/jcs-java-cloud-service-an-alternative-to-the-ssh-tunnel/) on how to create the extra Network Channel with proper External Listen Address.